# Django REST Framework update foreign key

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am trying to update an instance of the Indicator Component model that has a foreign key of the Indicator model. If I pass the primary key of the Indicator it return the following error:

> Cannot assign "4": "IndicatorComponent.indicator_id" must be a "Indicator" instance.

But if I pass the Indicator instance I get the following error:

> "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Indicator."

**Model**

```
class IndicatorComponent(models.Model):
    indicator_component_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Fecha',
        auto_now=False,
        null=True
    )
    indicator_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Indicator',
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Componente Indicador'
```

**Serializer**

```
class IndicatorComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.IndicatorComponent
        fields = (
            'indicator_component_id', 'name',
            'description', 'date', 'position_x', 'position_y',
            'size_width', 'size_height', 'indicator_id',
            'template_report_id', 'component_styles_id'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('creation_date', 'last_modified_date',)
```

What can i do to avoid this contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify foreignKey field name to indicator. If you name it indicator_id, the column in database is named indicator_id_id. And as default, the indicator_component_id field is unnecessary.

Try this:

```
class IndicatorComponent(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Fecha',
        auto_now=False,
        null=True
    )
    indicator = models.ForeignKey(
        'Indicator',
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Componente Indicador'


class IndicatorComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.IndicatorComponent
        fields = (
            'id', 'name',
            'description', 'date', 'position_x', 'position_y',
            'size_width', 'size_height', 'indicator_id',
            'template_report_id', 'component_styles_id'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('creation_date', 'last_modified_date',)
```

Comment: Thanks, It was fixed by changing the name of the indicator_id column to indicator